# Change dynamic full price color next to sale price in Woocommerce

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I am reaching out for a little bit of support.

I have Woocommerce products which display two prices side by side - full price & sale price.
Both of them use the same css styling in black. I would like to make the full price in lighter grey color.

The span:

`<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">312.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>`

`<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">51.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>`

I will be very, very happy if you can assist me how to adjust the CSS of the full price.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please not i added style color.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" style="color:grey;">312.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount" >51.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here i add class name for each price

```
<html>
<body>

<!-- fp stand for full price-->
<!-- sp stand for sale price-->

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount fp">312.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount sp" >51.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

on the .css file

```
.fp{
opacity: 0.5;
}

.sp{
opacity: 1;
}
```

if your stylesheet is inside HTML, or you don't want .css file use this

```
<html>
<body>

<!-- fp stand for full price-->
<!-- sp stand for sale price-->

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount fp" style="opacity: 0.5;">312.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount sp" style="opacity: 1;" >51.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
</body>
</html>
```

you also can change to more or less gray by changing the opacity.

here I made you the simpler one because it has same effect

```
<html>
<body>

<!-- fp stand for full price-->
<!-- sp stand for sale price-->

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount fp" style="opacity: 0.5;">312.00€</span>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount sp" style="opacity: 1;" >51.00€</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The prices for all listings are dynamic, therefore should I add the prices in the span? 

Much appreciated your support.